# Chirpstack Gateway Bridge Installation

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gateway, lorawan

I am working on an implementation of LoRa architecture on RaspberryPi. So in the process, it is needed to install this software package by Chirpstack called Gateway Bridge that converts LoRa packet forwarder format to JSON/Protobuf format that will be understood by my application. But the thing is while installing Gateway Bridge as mentioned in their official website [link](https://www.chirpstack.io/gateway-bridge/install/debian/) I am getting this error:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/mqtt_demo_3# sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1CE2AFD36DBCCA00
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.HwLDfOHwHV/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1CE2AFD36DBCCA00
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
```

On exploring on web I found that the setup key provided by them is not working.
Can we eliminate this error and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by keeping using command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 1CE2AFD36DBCCA00
```

instead of the command mentioned in the download page.